# Why is there no "List.reverse()" method in Java?

Tags: java, list, oop, interface

In Java, to reverse elements in a List, I need to use:

```
Collections.reverse(list)
```

I was just wondering why Java doesn't implement the reverse method within the `List` interface so that I could do the in-place reverse like this:

```
list.reverse()
```

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: how often would you use it?

Comment: @wero not very often honestly..

Comment: i guess the fact that it exists on Collections means that it wasn't forgotten. Probably the makers of the collection interfaces simply tried to keep those interfaces as "light" as possible.

Comment: @hanfeisun since `Collection.reverse` was introduced at the same time than `List` itself (JDK 1.2) it was most likely intention of the designers to not include it in the `List` interface but rather provide a helper method only.

Comment: This is a special case of the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3089284/3182664 (one could instantiate the same question with `fill`, `shuffle` and other static methods...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why is there no `List.reverse()` method in Java?

Because there is a `Collections.reverse(List)` method instead.

Because the API designers figured it was a bad idea to force *every* `List` implementation<sup>1</sup> to implement a method that wasn't used 99.9% of the time<sup>2</sup>.  This could be addressed by making the method "optional", but that has downsides too; e.g. runtime exceptions.

Because for some kinds of list (stream wrappers / adapters for example) implementing in-place reverse would be problematic.  It changes the memory usage characteristics of the list by requiring it to be reified.

Also note that the generic implementation ([source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.reverse%28java.util.List%29)) of `reverse()` that is provided by `Collection` uses `set` to swap elements.  It is close to optimal for the standard list types.

---

@shmosel comments:

> I assume OP is asking why it wasn't added as a default method, as List.sort() was.

Good point.  Possibly the 99.9% argument applies. Bear in mind that this would only help people with a codebase that is built using a Java 8 or later compilers, etc.

---

<sup>1 - This includes implementations in your codebase and 3rd-party libraries.</sup>

<sup>2 - 86% of statistics are made up for theatrical effect :-)</sup>

Comment: I assume OP is asking why it wasn't added as a default method, as `List.sort()` was.

Answer (score 5):

For the same reason that [`fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill-java.util.List-T-) and [`rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-) and [`shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) and [`swap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap-java.util.List-int-int-) and infinitely more possible list functions aren't declared in the `List` interface. They're not *part* of the "list" abstraction; rather, they can be implemented *on top of* that abstraction.

Once a `List` implements the methods already in the `List` interface, a `reverse` function can be written on top of the `List` abstraction without any knowledge of a particular `List` implementation. Therefore, it would be pointless to force every class implementing `List` to provide a custom implementation of `reverse` (and `fill`, `rotate`, `shuffle`, `swap`, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Note: This question is a very specific case of ["Why does the Collections class contain standalone (static) methods, instead of them being added to the List interface?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089284/why-does-the-collections-class-contain-standalone-static-methods-instead-of-t) - one could even consider is as a duplicate. Beyond that, arguing about the reasoning behind the decision for each individual method is reading tea leaves, and nobody can tell "*the* reason" for the design decision for the particular case of the `reverse` method (until, maybe Josh Bloch posts an answer here). Interestingly, this is a point that is not covered in the [Java Collections API Design FAQ](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html)...</sub>

---

Some of the other answers seem convincing at the first glance, but raise other questions. Particularly, some of them don't give a reason for the design decision at all. Even if there are other ways to emulate the behavior of a certain method, or when a method is not used "99.9% of all time", it can still make sense to include it in the interface.

---

Looking at the `List` interface, you will notice that you can basically implement **all** methods based on two others:

- `T get(int index)`
- `int size()`

(For a mutable list, you also need `set`). These are exactly the ones that are still abstract in `AbstractList`. So all other methods are rather "convenience" methods that can be implemented canonically, based on these two methods. In this regard, I think that [the answer Sam Estep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37896986/3182664) contains an important point: One could argue to implement dozens of other methods. And there would certainly be **good** reasons to do so. Having a look at the actual implementation of `Collections#reverse(List)`:

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size < REVERSE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=0, mid=size>>1, j=size-1; i<mid; i++, j--)
            swap(list, i, j);
    } else {
        ListIterator fwd = list.listIterator();
        ListIterator rev = list.listIterator(size);
        for (int i=0, mid=list.size()>>1; i<mid; i++) {
            Object tmp = fwd.next();
            fwd.set(rev.previous());
            rev.set(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

What is this `REVERSE_THRESHOLD` and `RandomAccess` thing there? Seriously, if I felt the necessity to introduce a tagging interface like `RandomAccess`, I would **strongly** question my design. Whenever you have a method like

```
void doSomethingWith(Type x) {
    if (x instanceof Special) doSomethingSpecial((Special)x);
    else doSomethingNormal(x);
}
```

then this is a **strong** sign that this should actually be a polymorphic method, which should be implemented accordingly for the `Special` type.

---

So yes, it have been justified to pull the `reverse` method into the interface, to allow a polymorphic implementation. The same applies to `fill` `rotate`, `shuffle`, `swap`, `sort` and others. Similarly, one could have introduced a static method like

```
Collections.containsAll(containing, others);
```

that offers what is now done with the `Collection#containsAll` method. But in general: The designers chose a particular set of methods that they found suitable. One of the reasonings behind leaving out certain methods may be given by one of the bottom lines of [the talk about "How to Design a Good API & Why it Matters" by Joshua Bloch](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/effective-api-design), one of the core designers of the Java Collections API:

### When in doubt, leave it out

Interestingly, of all the methods for which a polymorphic implementation (via a method in the `List` interface) could have been reasonable, **one** actually found its way into the interface, using a Java 8 `default` method:[`List#sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-). Maybe others, like `reverse`, will be added later...

Comment: Good answer. Regarding the last part, I doubt it will ever make it to the interface. sort() is very commonly called, whereas reverse() is quite rare. And introducing a new method in the interface, even as a default method, breaks things: subclasses already having a reverse() method with a different return type break. If the OP really wants that, kotlin extension functions provide an easy solution.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Collection` is an utilitarian class, that actually based on one of [SOLID](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) principle : 
**S - Single Responsibility Principle**

> This principle states that if we have **2 reasons** to change for a class, we have to split the functionality in two classes.

You have a class that play a some role, and if you need to manipulate of inner data you need to create some subsidiary class, that will plays another role.

Answer (score 3):

If you need `list.reverse()` you need to use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), when you can use just `list.reverseThis()`, see [this](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/MutableList.html). In JDK list, a lot of method (like sort, max, min) does not be added.

It's two different ways of API design:

1. A lot of method in Collection -> rich collection -> Eclipse
   Collections, **drawback**: a lot of rarely used method in List,
2. Only most used method and Utility class -> JDK
       collection, **drawback**: need to use Utility class like Collections,

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `why` question has already been answered, but here is a catch - [`List.reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) is going to be available since Java 21 (release date 19th September 2023):

```
System.out.println(List.of(1, 2, 3).reversed()); // [3, 2, 1]
```

**Note:** It returns a reverse-ordered [view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#view) of this collection.

Additional details in [JEP 431: Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

Comment: So, the answer is: "no reason!"

Answer (score 0):

Reverse is defined in Collections (with an extra (s)). This is not a part of collection hierarchy, rather it has been given as a part of utility class which can be used for different Lists.

Reversing a list is not a key part of defining a list , so its kept out of interface and given separately.  If defined in the interface, everyone will have to implement it, which may not be suitable for all.

The makers of collection could have build this in List hierarchy as well, ( Since most list derivations have an abstract class in between, they could have put it in any abstract class in between). However, to simplify everyone's life it makes sense to keep it in single utility class so that we don't have to figure out which class to look for all collection related utility functions.